# Android Studio gradle manifest merging failed

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-4.4-kitkat

After trying to run a project, an error appears:

```
Gradle: [AndroidManifest.xml:6, AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='14'> but library uses minSdkVersion='19'
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':myApp:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/systembartint.jar')
    compile project(':GooglePlayServices')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

> Used libraries: Google Maps, Android Support v4, SystemBarTint.

Looks like there is a `minSdkVersion=19` in Manifest of library. But what's the name of that library? Google Maps is a module with `minSdk` 14 and target 19. `SystemBarTint` with `minSdk` 10, I think. If I have to change manifest of library, how can I do it in jar file?

Comment: do you have a module called library?

Comment: Please post the full build.gradle file for your app.

Comment: Posted the full build.gradle. No module called library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library JAR files couldn't be causing this problem because they won't have manifest files that get merged. The problem has to be coming from the **GooglePlayServices** project that's in your dependencies. It's not clear what that is. If this isn't something of yours and you're just trying to use the Google Play Services library, there's an easier way. The easier way also replaces the way you've included the V4 support library.

In your SDK manager, make sure your **Android Support Repository** and **Google Repository** are installed.

Replace your dependencies block with this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'
    compile files('libs/systembartint.jar')
}
```

and remove the `android-support-v4.jar` and `google-play-services.jar` files from your libs directory.

Comment: Now it's OK. Thank you. In addition, developer have to add one line to Manifest file. See http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup